# Migrated Rails app db from MySQL to Postgresql and now finds and joins don't work since trailing spaces are no longer ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

rails and postgres experts...

This app uses (for example) a Book table with a column named vennum that contains a code with no trailing spaces.

The lookup table, Vendor, also contains this column but with trailing spaces existing.

In both MySQL and Postgres, this column is defined as a varchar(256).

When using MySQL, `Book.find('ABC')` finds the vendor with `vennum = 'ABC       '`, however this is not the case in Postgres. I have to pad the search value to 10 spaces.

I realize I could replace all vennum's in Vendor with a trimmed value but this is possibly not the only table behaving this way and this system had dozens of tables.

Is there a config setting somewhere (hopefully in database.yml) or in the pgloader command (used to do the migration) that tells Postgres to trim trailing spaces for searches?

Comment: no mysql removes all trailing spaces, simply trim the column

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28962449/how-to-use-trim-in-select-query-rails-or-in-sql-query